# from_unixtime and get_json_object in hive

Tags: json, hive

I'd like to ask how to use `from_unixtime` in a `get_json_object` command?

I've done a query like this:

> get_json_object(user_info, '$.xxxx.(from_unixtime(timestamp,
>   'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss'))) as time

(timestamp is in the unix format and I'd like to convert it), but it failed.

Is there any solution on this?

Comment: Extract json object first and then convert unixtime, e.g. `from_unixtime(get_json_object(user_info, '$.xxxx.'), 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss')`

Comment: @serge_k Hi Serge! thanks for your reply, but one question, get_json_object return value is string, right? so it cannot convert from unixtime, can it? need further explanation on this, thanks!